# Odds/Evens Javascript Value not updating between turns

Tags: javascript

all the code was given by the teacher and you just had to place it in the right spot. even working with the teacher we couldn't get it to update the "value" attribute in between turns. it updates at the finish of the game but not during? what are we not seeing? any help appreciated.. if you need to see html i can add as comment

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var getRandomNumber = function(max) {
var random;
if (!isNaN(max)) {
    random = Math.random(); //value >= 0.0 and < 1.0
    random = Math.floor(random * max); //value is an integer between 0 and max - 1
    random = random + 1; //value is an integer between 1 and max
}
return random;
};

var playGame = function() {
var odd = 0;
var even = 0;
var player, computer, total;
resetFields(); // clear any previous entries

while (odd < 50 && even < 50) {
    //get computers fingers
    computer = getRandomNumber(5);
    // get player's fingers
    player = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 5, or 999 to quit", 999));
    
    if (!isNaN(player) && player <= 5) {
        // show current round
        $("player").value = player;
        $("computer").value = computer;
        
        // update totals
        total = player + computer;
        if (total % 2 === 0) {
            even = even + total;
            $("even").value = even;
        } else {
            odd = odd + total;
            $("odd").value = odd;
        }
    }
    //if loop for player quitting
    if (player === 999) {
    resetFields();
    break;
    }
}
//after loop ends, determine winner
if (odd >= 50) { $("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "You WIN!"; }
else if (even >= 50) { $("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "You lose :("; }
else { $("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "You quit"; }

// set focus on button so you can play again
$("play").focus();
};

var resetFields = function() {
$("player").value = "0";
$("computer").value = "0";
$("odd").value = "0";
$("even").value = "0";
$("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
};

window.onload = function() {
$("play").onclick = playGame;
$("play").focus();
};
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Then `$("player")` should be `$("#player")` or `$(".player")`.

Comment: Please provide `resetFields()` and `getRandomNumber()` functions. Please append any console errors.

Comment: The general problem is that the browser doesn't re-render the page until the function returns. This is not the correct way to write an interactive application, you should use input fields with event listeners.

Comment: im extremely new at this, so im sorry for my issues im having with comments... smh.. first year student, first day using overflow

Comment: Please edit the question with additional information; code in comments is essentially illegible.

Comment: added all of the code on the js file.. thank you for your patience and answers.. the code was already written and given to us by Murachs JavaScript 2nd edition book.. we just had to form it in the playGame() function

Comment: Expanding on barmar's comment, your game is coded inside a JavaScript while loop that does not return until the game is finished. Generally speaking, any DOM manipulation done inside JavaScript code is not rendered by the browser until JavaScript code block has finished executing. Your code should work as expected except the changes will not display immediately. There are some workarounds but they are just hacks. The correct solution is to make the game event driven or use setTimeout... both require refactoring the code.